# relationship between two entities in different micro-services

Tags: jhipster

i have a question : does jhipster allow relationship between two entities in different micro-services
i have a :
1- customer microservice (with Customer entity)
2-farm microservice (with Farm entity)

it is possibl to do a ManytoOne relationship between Customer and Farm ? and How ?
this is my jdl file

```html
application {
  config {
    baseName gateway
    packageName com.privacy.gateway
    applicationType gateway 
    serverPort 8080
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
    databaseType mongodb
    cacheProvider hazelcast
    authenticationType oauth2
    buildTool maven
    clientFramework react
  }
  entities *
}

application {
  config {
    baseName soilmonitoring
    packageName com.privacy.soilmonitoring
    applicationType microservice
    serverPort 8081
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
    databaseType mongodb
    cacheProvider hazelcast
    authenticationType oauth2
    buildTool maven
  }
  entities SoilStream, SoilDevice
}

application {
  config {
    baseName customer
    packageName com.privacy.customer
    applicationType microservice
    serverPort 8082
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
    databaseType mongodb
    cacheProvider hazelcast
    authenticationType oauth2
    buildTool maven
  }
  entities Customer
}

application {
  config {
    baseName farm
    packageName com.privacy.farm
    applicationType microservice
    serverPort 8083
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
    databaseType mongodb
    cacheProvider hazelcast
    authenticationType oauth2
    buildTool maven
  }
  entities Farm
}

application {
  config {
    baseName farmservice
    packageName com.privacy.farmservice
    applicationType microservice
    serverPort 8084
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
    databaseType mongodb
    cacheProvider hazelcast
    authenticationType oauth2
    buildTool maven
  }
  entities FarmService
}




entity SoilDevice {
    name String required
    status DeviceStatus 
}

entity FarmService {
    name String required
    subscriptionPlan SubscriptionPlan 
}

entity Customer {   
    description String
}

entity Farm {   
    name String
    description String
}

enum DeviceStatus {
    ONLINE , OFFLINE
}

enum SubscriptionPlan {
    SMALL , MEDIUM , LARGE
}

entity SoilStream {
    soilTemp Float
    soilHum Float
    soilO2 Float
    soilCO2 Float
    soilEc Float
    soilPh Float
    lighting Float
    airTemp Float
    airHum Float
}


relationship ManyToMany{
    FarmService{farm} to Farm{farmservice}
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  SoilStream{soildevice} to SoilDevice
  Farm{customer} to Customer{farm}
}


paginate all with pagination
service all with serviceClass
dto all with mapstruct

microservice SoilStream, SoilDevice with soilmonitoring
microservice Farm  with farm
microservice Customer with customer
microservice FarmService with farmservice

deployment { 
  deploymentType docker-compose
  appsFolders [gateway , soilmonitoring , customer , farm, farmservice]
}
```

when i run jhipster import-jdl file.jdl i got the error :

ERROR! Error during import-jdl: Entities for the ManyToMany relationship from 'FarmService' to 'Farm' do not belong to the same application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because they are stored in 2 different databases. The only thing you can do is to use ID of the other entity, then depending on your use case you may aggregate data in an upper level service or in UI or duplicate partial data.

See the discussion in JHipster issue tracking to understand more: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9949